# date fiilter and display in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, filter

I want to filter date and display only the dates that are current dates and hide future dates. Here is my html code:

```
<div ng-controller="date">
        <div ng-repeat="d in dates">
            <ul>
                <div ng-show='(show==true)' ng-hide='(show==false)'><li>{{d.thisDate() | date:"mediumDate"}}</li></div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here is my angular.js code:

```
var milo = angular.module('milo',[]);

function date($scope){

$scope.dates = [
{
    id: 0,
    thisDate: function(){
        return  new Date();
    }
},
{
    id: 1,
    thisDate: function(){
        return  new Date();
    }
},
{
    id: 2,
    thisDate: function(){
        return 141232741945463;
    }
},


];

$scope.show = function(){
    if (thisDate == new Date()){
        return true;
    }
    else if (thisDate > new Date()){
        return false;
    }
};
};


milo.controller('date', date);
```

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind, but for now it doesnt help me :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
if (thisDate <= new Date()){
    return true;
}
else if (thisDate > new Date()){
    return false;
}
```

because your date will define at an instant t and the show() function will be called at an instant t+1...

Comment: Hi, I have changed the code a bit and uploaded it to the jsfiddle.net. Here it is - http://jsfiddle.net/adeling/Tb9j5/21 .Once I use ng-show directive everything disappears.